# GastbyJS and Redux: Image not displaying

Tags: image, reactjs, redux, react-redux, gatsby

I am using GatsbyJS and Redux to pull 'image' data from 'Projects_reducer' reducer, to show up in my container. My problem is: my image isn't recognised and doesn't show up on my screen.

I have tried to import my images into the container first, like this:

```
import thirtyImg from "../images/thirtyImage.svg";
```

Then, I made the 'image' property value thirtyImg:

```
image: 'thirtyImg'
```

Then, back in my container, I try to get to the data by writing:

```
<img style={{height: '70px', width: '70px'}} src={this.props.project.image}/>
```

but it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I replace the this.props.project.image with thirtyImg, it works. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried to replace the image property value with the appropriate file path and remove the image imports from my container, but this isn't working either. Why is this happening and how can I fix this??

Comment: 'thirtyImg' ? string?

Comment: okay, i got it: I imported the imgs into my reducer and changed the property value so that it was no longer a string. thanks